# AWS event driven approach - Cloud Watch vs S3 event notification

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudwatch, event-driven

I am building an event-driven system, which starts as soon as a new file lands S3.
I am evaluating different ways of achieving that and using Cloud Watch Rule + API Trail is an option.
This is the Cloud Watch Event pattern as it is:

```
    {
  "source": [
    "aws.s3"
  ],
  "detail-type": [
    "AWS API Call via CloudTrail"
  ],
  "detail": {
    "eventSource": [
      "s3.amazonaws.com"
    ],
    "eventName": [
      "PutObject"
    ],
    "requestParameters": {
      "bucketName": [
        "mysupertest88"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Like that, it triggers the rule for every file landing into the bucket but trying to filter by key and wildcard does not work:

```
"requestParameters": {
      "bucketName": [
        "mysupertest88"
      ],
      "key": ["myprefix/mysecondprefix/*"]
    }
```

It works just if I specify a key with matches without a wildcard, I think because the symbol '*' is a valid char in S3 objects.
**An alternative is** to filter directly at Trail level:
[image: API Trail]

but I do not see that as a nice option, as API Trail is often out of developer's control.
**An additional alternative is to use content-filtering: (nice new feature, but you have to create the rule through EventBridge)**

```
    {
  "source": [
    "aws.s3"
  ],
  "detail-type": [
    "AWS API Call via CloudTrail"
  ],
  "detail": {
    "eventSource": [
      "s3.amazonaws.com"
    ],
    "eventName": [
      "PutObject"
    ],
    "requestParameters": {
      "bucketName": [
        "mysupertest88"
      ],
      "key": [
        {
          "prefix": "a/c"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Last S3 event [notification](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html) is the old way to accomplish this? What is your experience with that? Any pro and cons that are not easy to catch without experience?

Answer (score 3):

Since your objective is to start an action "as soon as a new file lands S3", CT may not satisfy your requirement. This is because it can take up 15 minutes for delivery of the API events. From AWS [faq](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudtrail/faqs/):

> Typically, CloudTrail delivers an event within **15 minutes** of the API call.

In contrast, S3 events should be faster. From AWS [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html):

> Amazon S3 event notifications are designed to be delivered at least once. Typically, event notifications are delivered in **seconds but can sometimes take a minute or longer**.

Answer (score 0):

[image]yes, s3 notifications are much faster:

https://eoins.medium.com/comparing-two-ways-to-trigger-lambda-from-s3-b5da8cfe1aee